Restore local database backup to remote server
I have .bak file of  SQL Server database in my machine. I need to restore it in a remote SQLServer.
Because of policy rules, there's no way I can copy the file directly on the machine and I can't place it in a share folder.
I've tried to generate a .bacpack file but it gives me an error error due to synonyms.
Any ideas?

How big is the database on disk, and how many objects exist inside it?

Can't tell if you're kidding, but I've worked with databases that were 10,000x as big, and single tables 5,000x as big. 150 MB is pretty tiny lol. How many tables, views, procedures, functions, etc, exist in it roughly?

So you have sysadmin access to target server but no OS access?
I so you can

create a table with blob varbinary(max) field
populate this field with your backup file from the client
extract contents of varbinary(max) to server
verify your backup via RESTORE VERIFYONLY
restore your database

If your backup is big (lets say 150Gb and not 150Mb) you can
Split it to pieces by archiver (for example 7za https://www.7-zip.org/)
or perform backup your database in multiple files (up to 64)
In first case you should

upload/download command line archiver (it's small)
enable xp_cmdshell
upload/download every piece of backup
extract full backup from pieces
verify it via RESTORE VERIFYONLY
perform restore

Note - you don't have to load everything at once, you can do it piece by piece truncating buffer table after every successful transfer.
Here is the links I used to populate the table
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/t-sql-tuesday-006-blobs-filestream-and-powershell
$server = "Z002\sql2k8"
$database = "AdventureWorks2008"
$query = "INSERT Production.ProductPhoto2 VALUES (@ThumbNailPhoto, @ThumbnailPhotoFileName)"
$filepath = "C:\Users\u00\hotrodbike_black_small.gif"
$ThumbnailPhotoFileName = get-childitem $filepath | select -ExpandProperty Name
 
$connection=new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection
$connection.ConnectionString="Server={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=True" -f $server,$database
$command=new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query,$connection)
$command.CommandTimeout=120
$connection.Open()
 
$fs = new-object System.IO.FileStream($filePath,[System.IO.FileMode]'Open',[System.IO.FileAccess]'Read')
$buffer = new-object byte[] -ArgumentList $fs.Length
$fs.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)
$fs.Close()
 
$command.Parameters.Add("@ThumbNailPhoto", [System.Data.SqlDbType]"VarBinary", $buffer.Length)
$command.Parameters["@ThumbNailPhoto"].Value = $buffer
$command.Parameters.Add("@ThumbnailPhotoFileName", [System.Data.SqlDbType]"NChar", 50)
$command.Parameters["@ThumbnailPhotoFileName"].Value = $ThumbnailPhotoFileName
$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
 
$connection.Close()

And here is the link I used to extract the data from table to SQL Server
https://sqlrambling.net/2020/04/04/saving-and-extracting-blob-data-basic-examples/
## https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/890.export-sql-server-blob-data-with-powershell.aspx
## Export of "larger" Sql Server Blob to file
## with GetBytes-Stream.
# Configuration data
$Server = ".\&amp;lt;Instance&amp;gt;";         # SQL Server Instance.
$Database = "Blob_Test";
$Dest = "C:\BLOBTest\BLOBOut\";             # Path to export to.
$bufferSize = 8192;               # Stream buffer size in bytes.
# Select-Statement for name &amp;amp; blob
# with filter.
$Sql = "SELECT [PictureName]
              ,[PictureData]
        FROM dbo.PicturesTest";            
 
# Open ADO.NET Connection
$con = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
$con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$Server;" +
                        "Integrated Security=True;" +
                        "Initial Catalog=$Database";
$con.Open();            
 
# New Command and Reader
$cmd = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand $Sql, $con;
$rd = $cmd.ExecuteReader();            
 
# Create a byte array for the stream.
$out = [array]::CreateInstance('Byte', $bufferSize)            
 
# Looping through records
While ($rd.Read())
{
    Write-Output ("Exporting: {0}" -f $rd.GetString(0));
    # New BinaryWriter
    $fs = New-Object System.IO.FileStream ($Dest + $rd.GetString(0)), Create, Write;
    $bw = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter $fs;            
 
    $start = 0;
    # Read first byte stream
    $received = $rd.GetBytes(1, $start, $out, 0, $bufferSize - 1);
    While ($received -gt 0)
    {
       $bw.Write($out, 0, $received);
       $bw.Flush();
       $start += $received;
       # Read next byte stream
       $received = $rd.GetBytes(1, $start, $out, 0, $bufferSize - 1);
    }            
 
    $bw.Close();
    $fs.Close();
}            
 
# Closing &amp;amp; Disposing all objects
$fs.Dispose();
$rd.Close();
$cmd.Dispose();
$con.Close();            
 
Write-Output ("Finished");


This is... amazing.  I am in awe.   However, before taking this approach, I would look at using Azure Blob Storage.  see here https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/backup-and-restore-sql-database-to-azure-blob-storage  If you have sysadmin access to the target SQL Server, that's all you need.  Or if you are in the same network, put up a share on YOUR machine and then SQL reach over to yours.
